# Wrong div width when getting it with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, coding-style

I'm trying to get div's width with javascript. Initially div's width is undefined, ie width depends on amount of text on it. Is it possible to get width of this kind of div? I'm trying to do it with following javascript code, but i'm getting width  differerent from Chrome console when i'm inspecting div

```
var mydiv = document.getElementById("error_message");
var curr_width = mydiv.clientWidth;
alert(curr_width);
```

Thank you for your attention

Comment: Initially an unstyled div will have a width equal to its container's width. That's due to the default `display:block` styling.

Comment: Can you add the HTML too ... im not sure your DIV will be the width of a the text within it ... its a BLOCK element

Comment: it's generated with `document.write("<div id=\"error_message\">Wrong username or password!</div>");` and css is `div#error_message{
 display:block;
 position: absolute;
 padding: 2px;
 top: 0px; 
 border: 1px solid #FF0000; 
 background: #FFCCFF;
 font-family: Arial;
 font-size: 13px;
 color: #FF0000;
}`

Comment: And what is the width thats being shown in the alert ? what did you expect is to be ?

Comment: in alert it is 1008 and in console it is 183, so i'm expecting 183

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use offsetWidth

clientWidth is calculated width, offsetWidth is the one in "Chrome inspect element" (i think)

also read the comments :P

Comment: but your div is also undifined initially?

Comment: i've got it worked! but sumetimes when i'm refreshing page it's printing right width nad sometimes wrong width again!

Comment: dont use `document.write()` but create node with js or jQuery, and launch your script in onload...

Answer (score 1):

While the OP doesn't specify one way or the other, if you happen to have jQuery available, you can always use this:

```
var curr_width = $('#error_message').width();
```

Comment: i'm getting following code when i'm alert(curr_width) `function (a){var f=this[0];if(!f)return a==null?null:this;if(d.isFunction(a))return this.each(function(b){var c=d(this);c[e](a.call(this,b,c[e]()))});if(d.isWindow(f)){var g=f.document.documentElement["client"+c];return f.document.compatMode==="CSS1Compat"&&g||f.document.body["client"+c]||g}if(f.nodeType===9)return ...`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem! I was trying to create div directly in javascript, without defining div on html body. So inside of  tag i've created

```
<div id="error_message" style="visibility:hidden;"></div>
```

and it's worked! 
Final javascript code is:

```
document.write("<div id=\"error_message\">Wrong username or password!</div>");
var mydiv = document.getElementById("error_message");
var curr_width = mydiv.offsetWidth;
alert(curr_width);
```